# Run a specific pytest-bdd scenario from VSCode UI

Tags: visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, pytest, bdd, pytest-bdd

I'm looking for a way to run specific Pytest BDD scenarios from VSCode UI. At the moment the UI can run all scenarios in a class, but not specific scenarios.

Project structure:

```
tests
   |-- features
      |--sample_tests.feature
   |-- step_defs
      |--test_example.py
```

sample_tests.feature

```
Feature: Sample tests

Scenario: Test number one
    Given I have 100 pounds
    Then I have money
    
@second
Scenario: Test number two
    Given I open some page
    Then I verify the header is displayed
```

test_example.py

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
full_path = f"{cwd}/tests/features/sample_test.feature"

@scenario(full_path, 'Test number one')
def test_method_name():
    logger.info("End of the first test")
    pass

@given("I have 100 pounds")
def hundred_pounds():
    logger.info("Inside I have 100 pounds")


@then("I have money")
def have_money():
    logger.info("Inside I have money")


@scenario(full_path, 'Test number two')
def test_first_browser_test():
    logger.info("End of the second test")
    pass

@given("I open some page")
def open_page(driver):
    driver.get("www.google.com")
    logger.info("google opened")


@then("I verify the header is displayed")
def verify_page():
    logger.info("Second browser step")
```

On the image below, that's how it works currently:

- Running `test_example_steps` runs both tests
- Running `test_method_name` or `test_first_browser_test` doesn't do anything (this is what I'm trying to make work)
- Clicking on "Go to Test" on `test_example_steps` takes you to `test_example_steps.py`
- Clicking on "Go to Test" on `test_method_name` or `test_first_browser_test` takes you to `/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_bdd/scenario.py`

[image]

[image]

I tried VSC and Pycharm with the same result. The only way I could run a specific scenario is the command line, e.g. `pytest -m "second"`. But how to do it via UI? Expected to be able to run individual tests from IDE UI, as using command line is not my preferred way of running these locally.